# comma seperated number is valid in eval() function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My target is verify whether the given string is in expression format or not ?

var a = '1+2';  // valid string

eval(a)  // get 3

var b = '1 * 2'; // valid string

eval(b) // get 2

var c = '1 , 2'; // Invalid string

eval(c) // get 2

var d = '1 , 2, 3'; // Invalid string

eval(d) // get 3

In last two case, I passed invalid string, but I got value.

How I validate this type of invalid string

Thank u

Comment: Read about the comma operator.

Answer (score 2):

Comma operator works like below:

`eval('exp1, exp2');`

executes `exp1` first, then execute `exp2`...so you get value of `exp2` as the output.

> NOTE: You should use eval wisely in your code...it may hurt you :)

Answer (score 1):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

More details - [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

That is why the last two strings return 2 and 3. The string you passed is valid.